# How to test if a method from a base class has been called and executed using google mock?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, inheritance, googletest, googlemock

I am trying to test if a method from a base class has been **called and executed** using a Google Mock test. I have a simple BankAccount class that implements a function withdraw. In the BankAccount.h file:

```
class BankAccount {

public:

    BankAccount();

    int withdraw(int balance, int withdrawalAmount);

};
```

In the BankAccount.cpp file:

```
#include "BankAccount.h"

BankAccount::BankAccount()
{
}

int BankAccount::withdraw(int balance, int withdrawalAmount)
{
    if (withdrawalAmount <= balance)
    {
        balance -= withdrawalAmount;
    }

    return balance;
}
```

In a test.h file I have:

```
#include "BankAccount.h"

class MockBankAccount : public BankAccount {

public:

    MockBankAccount();

    MOCK_METHOD2(withdraw, int(int balance, int withdrawalAmount));
};
```

My MockBankAccount class inherits from BankAccount class.

In my test.cpp file:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include "test.h"

using namespace testing;

// Constructors/Destructors

MockBankAccount::MockBankAccount()
{
}

TEST(WithdrawAccountTest, Withdraw)
{
    MockBankAccount mockAccount;

    EXPECT_CALL(mockAccount, withdraw(5, 1))
        .Times(1);

    mockAccount.withdraw(5, 1);
}

// Main
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

I want to check that withdraw method is called and executed from the BankAccount class (i.e. BankAccount::withdraw is executed). When I run the test, it passes and I expect that withdraw has been called and executed, however if I place a breakpoint on BankAccount::withdraw and debug, I can see that it never actually reaches the method from the base class. Is there a way to use Google Mock to check BankAccount::withdraw, such as by using another method (composition rather than inheritance, templates, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

I want to try to give an acceptable answer to you.

First of all, the code does what it is supposed to be. You call in the test the "mock-method" and the test passes of course. But the test will never call the method of the base class (and that is correct). By the way, it makes no sense to test, if a method is called and then call this method directly.

But lets talk about Mocking. You just need Mocks, when the tested class has dependencies to other classes.
Consider a class `Person`, which has a dependency to the `BankAccount` class and you want to test the class `Person`. **While testing, it is important to test an object in isolation.** Thats why you don't want, that `Person` talked to a real instance from the `BankAccount` class. And here comes the mocking...

Imagine that there is the class Person in addition to your classes:

```
class Person {
public:
    Person(BankAccount *account, int balance) : ba(account), balance(balance) {}
    int getMoneyfromBankAccount(int withdrawalAmount) {
        ba->withdraw(balance, withdrawalAmount);
    }
private:
    BankAccount *ba;
    int balance;
}
```

And the test changes to:

```
TEST(PersonTest, testWhenPersonGetsMoneyFromTheBankAccount_withdrawIsCalled)
{
   MockBankAccount mockAccount;

   EXPECT_CALL(mockAccount, withdraw(5, 1))
      .Times(1);

   Person p(&mockAccount, 5);
   p.getMoneyfromBankAccount(1);
}
```

and don't forget to make the bank account method virtual:

```
virtual int BankAccount::withdraw(int balance, int withdrawalAmount)
```

After all, if you just want to test the method `withdraw()` from the class `BankAccount`, you don't need any mocks.